# Qgis gdalogr:contour is not generating output

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-processing

I am trying to use gdal:contour script in Qgis console and then script. Here is code which I tried write to console.

```
raster = QgsRasterLayer('C:/Users/Bulva.user/Desktop/test_raster.asc', "DEM")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([raster])
processing.runalg("gdalogr:contour", raster, 1.0, "ELEV", None, "C:/Users/Bulva.user/Desktop/contour.shp")
```

the output of console is:

```
{'OUTPUT_VECTOR': 'C:/Users/Bulva.user/Desktop/countour.shp'}
```

but there is no shapefile as output. I tried **processing.runandload** and there is a problem with loading layer, because shapefile wasn't generated.

I tried it few days ago and I swear it worked but today I have no idea why it is not working.

This my log in Log Messages Panel > Processing:

```
2016-05-11T11:45:35 2   Problem with OTB installation: OTB was not found or is not correctly installed
2016-05-11T11:47:25 0   GDAL execution console output
            Usage: gdal_contour [-b <band>] [-a <attribute_name>] [-3d] [-inodata]

                                [-snodata n] [-f <formatname>] [-i <interval>]

                                [-f <formatname>] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...] [[-lco NAME=VALUE] ...]

                                [-off <offset>] [-fl <level> <level>...]

                                [-nln <outlayername>] [-q]

                                <src_filename> <dst_filename>



            FAILURE: Too many command options.
```

and in OGR:

```
2016-05-11T11:47:25 1   Data source is invalid ()
2016-05-11T11:47:25 1   Data source is invalid ()
```

Comment: Your path `C:/Users/Bulva.user/`is problematic (. is non ASCII)

Comment: Yes, it is working on other computer. Is there any way how start algorithm on computer where is name of user with "."? I can't change this name. Or I have to create folder in Users? You can put your previous comment as answer, I will mark it. Thanks for reply.

Comment: It is working on new 2.14.2.2 qgis version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How @gene said, the problem is '.' in my username (C:Users/firstname.secondname) on computer.

In QGIS 2.14 and 2.16 it is working fine.