# r.mapcalc error, no output

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, raster-calculator, error

I am getting the following OGR error when using Grass r.mapcalc in QGIS 2.18 on Windows 7:

*Data source is invalid ()*

The process seems to run, the window shuts but there is no output.

This problem has been diagnosed in the following link as caused by non-ASCII characters in path used:
  [Qgis gdalogr:contour is not generating output](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193129/qgis-gdalogrcontour-is-not-generating-output).

My user also uses this Firstname.Surname format but the directory I am trying to save to is not in this path.

Is my username the issue?

Both rasters tested have the same number of pixels, extent and spatial resolution. Here are my parameters:

[image]

Similarly, SAGA raster calculator, produces no output and the following python error:

*AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TYPE_RASTER'*